# having difficulty with creating constraint in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, constraints

I have a table with contact as one of the column with constraint following the pattern of (000)0000000000

```
create table patient
(USERNUM INT PRIMARY KEY,
CONTACT varchar(15) constraint check_contact check (contact like '%([0-9]*3)[0-9]*10%'),
age int constraint check_age check (age >0 and age <=100),
location varchar(50)
);
```

This does not allow me to insert the record though the pattern of number is same.
I have altered my table with below command as an alternative

```
alter table patient add contact varchar(15) constraint ch_contact 
check (SUBSTRING(contact, 1, 1) = '(' and SUBSTRING(contact, 5, 1) = ')' 
and SUBSTRING(contact, 2, 4) like '[0-9]' and SUBSTRING(contact, 6, 15) like '[0-9]');
```

but it does not allow me to insert the record as below

```
insert into patient (USERNUM, CONTACT, AGE, LOCATION)
VALUES (5, '(000)0234567890', 34, 'VIZAG');
'''
```

Comment: Unfortunately, SQLite's `LIKE` operator does not support extended/regex syntax as you have used it.  You will need some other way to make the assertion.

Comment: Yes I noticed that @TimBiegeleisen the same create statement allowed me to insert records in MSSQL. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: I partially recant what I said in the above comment; SQLite has a `GLOB` operator which might be workable here, see my answer below.  But no, it does not formally support regex proper (unless you import a library, which may not even be possible in your case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use the `GLOB` operator here:

```sql
CONTACT varchar(15) CONSTRAINT check_contact
    CHECK (contact GLOB '([0-9][0-9][0-9])[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```